# How to reduce the use of viewBinding, to call (text,edit)views From layout

Tags: android, kotlin, binding

I want to decrease the use of binding in my code

```
fun setVisibility() {
                    binding.tvFact.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    binding.tvTimeStamp.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    binding.progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                }
```

Comment: What your expecting... You just put 3lines of code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not like the syntax try this:

```
binding.apply{
  tvFact.visibility = View.VISIBLE
  tvTimeStamp.visibility = View.VISIBLE
  progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
}
```

Comment: I prefer `with(binding)` personally (since you're not using the result of the `apply`) but that's personal taste, same thing really! Also if you're using the `core-ktx` library you can do `tvFact.isVisible = true`

Comment: I also use with(binding) but the questioner looks like a person who would use apply that is why i wrote that :d

Comment: Yeah it's all good!

Comment: thanks guys, both are good. Actually i was looking for method with using ''core-ktx'' But didn't know what it was called

Answer (score 0):

You can set these values `in XML itself` as default ones, so it won't process each time to set it.

```
<View
...
   android:visibility="gone">

</>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks but i needed to change it after i set the values